# Docker container stats empty after exit

Tags: docker

I am trying to measure total `cpu_usage` for the docker container using `GET /containers/$CONTAINER_ID/stats` API and while the container is running the endpoint returns meaningful data:

```
{"cpu_usage":{"total_usage":213788430,"percpu_usage":[1917539,288587,145139232,1911156,5966276,4931989,11474144,1252778,593573,847283,39465873,0],"usage_in_kernelmode":20000000,"usage_in_usermode":160000000}
```

but once it exits everything is zeroed out:

```
{"cpu_usage":{"total_usage":0,"usage_in_kernelmode":0,"usage_in_usermode":0}
```

How can I get the total CPU usage for a docker container which has finished it's work?

Comment: You may want to `pause` the container, pull the data, then stop it. Since the stop command terminates the running instance, and as you have observed, usage data is zeroed out. Pausing might give you the `stop` like state and an opportunity to pull the data before termination.